# Why is this defaultIfEmpty choosing ienumerable<char> instead of string?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, defaultifempty

```
 from a in mainDoc.XPathSelectElements("//AssembliesMetrics/Assembly/@Assembly")
                            let aVal=a.Value
                            where aVal.IsNullOrEmpty( )==false&&aVal.Contains(" ")
                            select aVal.Substring(0, aVal.IndexOf(' '))
                              into aName
                              let interestedModules=new[ ] { "Core", "Credit", "Limits", "Overdraft" }
                              where aName.Contains(".")
                              let module=
                                interestedModules
                                .FirstOrDefault(x => aName
                                  .StartsWith(x, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                              where module!=null
                              group aName by module.DefaultIfEmpty() // ienumerable<char>, why?
                                into groups
                                select new { Module=groups.Key??"Other", Count=groups.Count( ) };
```

Comment: if it is not clear, I have a list of assemblies from an xml file, where I want to see how many are in an `interested modules` namespace along with the `interestedModules` name or other if it's not one i'm particularly interested in

Comment: What are you expecting it to return?

Comment: Why are you calling it at all?

Comment: because I don't want the group by filtering out results where module is null

Comment: Then why do you have `where module!=null`?  See my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`module` is a string.

String implements `IEnumerable<char>`.

You're calling the `Enumerable.DefaultIfEmpty` method, which extends `IEnumerable<T>`.
This method can never return anything other than an `IEnumerable<T>`.

**EDIT**: If you want to replace `null` values of `module` with a non-null value, you can use the null-coalescing operator:

```
group aName by module ?? "SomeValue"
```

However, `module` will never actually be `null`, because of the `where module!=null` clause.
You should then also remove `??"Other"` from the final `select` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Because, in this case, `module` is a string:

```
let module = interestedModules
                 .FirstOrDefault(x => aName
                 .StartsWith(x, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

When you call any of the IEnumerable extensions on a string, it decomposes into an `IEnumerable<char>`.